# iTerm2: Alt-Dot functionality with Cmd-Dot

Tags: macos, bash, iterm2

Is there any known way to achieve the "insert last command argument"-functionality that is usually available in Bash by typing Alt-. (Alt and period) on OSX using iTerm2?

The ways I know this should be possible is by the two key-sequences:

`Alt + .`
`Esc + .`

The Esc-. one works, but the Alt-. does not. Not with Alt-. or Cmd-.

Comment: See also [Get a command from history without execution in bash](//superuser.com/q/623266/150988).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This looks like part of the EMACS readline bash key bindings i.e. they appear to be key combinations that are used in EMACS and emulated or add-ons to bash, or something.  Mine work as yours do, unfortunately, but I have a workaround since you are speaking with respect to iTerm2:

Go into the Preferences for the profile of the Terminal session you'd like to inflict this upon, and establish the key-binding as illustrated thus:

[image]

This is probably not the solution that you are looking for, however it should work for you in a pinch.

Comment: This works great for me.  If it's not the right solution, what is?

Answer (score 5):

You simply need to modify the behavior of the Option key to achieve the desired result.

If you navigate to the Keyboard Behavior section of the Keys tab in the Profile setting, you'll see that the "Left/Right option (⌥) key acts as:" choices are set to "Normal" (as in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTwVT.png) in [Bill's answer](//superuser.com/a/704301)). Update these to "+Esc" and apply. 
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+**<kbd>.</kbd>**
will now provide the last argument of the previous command.

Comment: Edit your answer and provide detail steps to accomplish what you describe

Comment: @iviarki: This will affect the behavior of all (Alt)+ key combinations, won't it?

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted. The above works. Although compared to other answer here you'd use 'alt' (option) as oppose to command button.

Answer (score 1):

`iTerm2 > Settings > Profiles > Keys > Left Option key > Esc+`

[image]

Comment: This sets if for ⌥, not ⌘. Still, better than nothing.